# Right value of magnetic_declination_radians

Tags: ros, navigation, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to configure a dual EKF plus navsat_transform setup for robot_localization and I am not sure of how to input the value of magnetic_declination_radians.

Magnetic declination for the place I live is  -9° 16' (W) and the [webpage](https://www.magnetic-declination.com/) I am using says: "Declination is NEGATIVE (WEST)". So, the value of the `magnetic_declination_radians` parameter should be -0.152425 or should I use the negative value of 0.152425?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380637/right-value-of-magnetic_declination_radians/) by [gmsanchez](https://answers.ros.org/users/75415/gmsanchez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's confusing, and I need to update the documentation, but everything is calculated in the ENU frame for `navsat_transform_node`. So a western declination (counter-clockwise) would be positive. In your case, you'd want 0.152425.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2022-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gmsanchez](https://answers.ros.org/users/75415/gmsanchez/) on 2022-10-28**:
Thanks Tom for the answer.

If the declination is around 0.152425 radians, would you expect that the EKF yaw to have a 0.152425 offset relative to the IMU yaw?

I am still struggling with these concepts and I hope to get robot_localization working outdoors soon. What kind of error would you expect using an Ardusimple RTK GPS (cm accuracy) with an XSens MTi-630 IMU? I calibrated the IMU but I can't get repeatability on the results.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2023-01-05**:
No, declination has nothing to do with the EKF. It's solely a concept that applies to `navsat_transform_node`. It's just used to correct your raw IMU data (which points to magnetic north, and not true north) in `navsat_transform_node`. The EKF's heading is utterly independent of anything in `navsat_transform_node`. In fact, your EKF might not even fuse IMU data. It might just fuse yaw velocity from your wheel encoders.